# Forgot to shelve my code in TFS. What are my options now?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I made some code changes (in VS 2010), and did not check in or shelve my latest changes.  Unfortunately, my laptop had a heating problem and I can't use it for another week (it's going for service).  I have the hard drive with me though, so I can probably access the code from another machine.  But how do I do it without messing up the state in TFS? If I copy-paste all my code from the hard drive into the other machine, VS will check out all my files right?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would check the files out that you think are changed (you can use a tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to see which files have changed), copy the updated files from the old drive, and shelve or check them back in.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are in a solution and you have the complete structure on your disk try if the "Go online" feature is available if you open the solution.

"File => SourceControl => Go online" or go to another machine and map your workspace to your disk with the changed source code.

(I would create a temporary private workspace for that situation and delete it after successfull merging/checkin).

I suppose if you open the solution and it has a valid source control binding, you get a message that your solution is right to go online.

If this dialog appears select "yes", all changes are correctly detected and you can merge/checkin in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks...I ended up following @competent_tech's solution this time.  Hopefully I'll not have to do this again, but if so I'll give this method a shot.

Answer (score 0):

On the new machine get the latest code from branch, which comes with previously checked-out TFS version by you, then copy/paste the files from harddisk to replace tfs verison.

Comment: Normally I would check the entire branch out before replacing the files and use tfpt uu (tfs power tools undo unchanged) to do the hardwork finding out what is different.  Then do a final review before checking in or shelving.